# Force login for a subdirectory within wordpress install

Tags: login

I am using a simple force login plugin that works great "Force Login
By Kevin Vess".

I have a subfolder (right now in /wp-content/subdir/") that i want to also force login for but cant figure how.

Is there a way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was easier than i thought

```
<body>

<?php

chdir( '../' );
include 'wp-load.php';

if ( is_user_logged_in() ) :  ?>

// Do stuff

<?php endif; ?>
```